# Error "jsPDF canvas plugin not installed" with html2pdf.js and Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I'm migrating an Angular app to Webpack which uses the `html2pdf.js` library.

After having added the package with `yarn add html2pdf.js@0.9.0` and added the `import 'html2pdf.js'`, when I call `html2pdf(element, opt)`, it shows an alert message :

```
jsPDF canvas plugin not installed
```

To me it seems like the jspdf lib is loaded, but the canvas plugin is missing or miss-loaded.

This seems to come from the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) package [where come from this alert](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/src/deprecated/html2pdf.js#L16).

Could anyone help me on getting this working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by aliasing html2pdf.js as html2pdf :

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  html2pdf: 'html2pdf.js',
  ...
}));
```

I have also changed the way to use `html2pdf` (but it didn't solved the issue when I did it).

I was using it like this :

```
    var element = document.getElementById('workstations-peripherals-table')
    var opt = {
      filename: 'grid.pdf',
      margin:   10,
      jsPDF:    {
        format: 'a4',
        orientation: 'landscape'
      }
    }
    html2pdf(element, opt)
```

And now I'm using the promise way:

```
    var element = document.getElementById('workstations-peripherals-table')
    var opt = {
      filename: 'grid.pdf',
      margin:   10,
      jsPDF:    {
        format: 'a4',
        orientation: 'landscape'
      }
    }
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save()
```